# how to sort a vector without loosing its order c++?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, stdvector

```
int a[10], b[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
        b[i] = i;
    }
    sort(b, b + 10, [=](int i, int j) { return a[i] < a[j]; }) return 0;
```

The above code stores the order of the sorted array in the array `b[10]`
How do I do this in a `vector<int>`?
don't answer  implementations using the `vector<pair<int,int>>`

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't do basically the exact same thing with vectors, substituting iterators where needed?

Comment: If you change `int a[10];` to `std::vector<int> a(10);` the code you already have should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::sort(b, b + 10, ...);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
std::sort(std::begin(b), std::end(b), ...);
```

Now, if you change `b` from `int b[10];` to `std::vector<int> b(10);` the latter code still works and does the right thing. No further changes are required if you change `int a[10];` to `std::vector<int> a(10);`.

Also, there is no point copying array/vector `a` into the lambda capture with `[=]`, take it by reference with `[&]` capture.

Complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a;
    for(int n = 10, value; n-- && (std::cin >> value);) // Read up to 10 values.
        a.push_back(value);
    // Create index of a and sort it.
    using size_type = decltype(a.size()); // Pedantically, should a have a custom allocator with a custom size_type.
    std::vector<size_type> a_index(a.size());
    std::iota(std::begin(a_index), std::end(a_index), size_type{});
    std::sort(std::begin(a_index), std::end(a_index), [&](size_type i, size_type j) { return a[i] < a[j]; });
}
```